# Does the Play! Framework have an equivalent of phpinfo?

Tags: playframework-2.0

Actually, that was my entire question, "Does the Play! Framework have an equivalent of phpinfo?"  I would like to get some info on my dev stack out on a web page.

Comment: No, it doesn't what do you need to find?

Comment: I'm just poking around play for the first time and need more info & context. Something like phpinfo would be awesome because it would show me existing configurations/settings/plugins/etc AND things that I don't currently know anything about.  Is there a good way to get a comprehensive overview of my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no equivalent of the `phpinfo` page in java. Do not forget the Play framework is nothing more than a Java application with several included librairies. However, the only information you could need for a Playframework application is :

- The Play version of the project. You can find it in the `plugins.sbt` file.
- Project dependencies, you can find those in the `build.scala` file.